# PHP Session Error using plesk on a linux server

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress, stream

My friend hosts a website on a `linux server` using `plesk`.

He was getting `404 error` on almost every page, and the error code he was getting is pasted below: (I couldn't post more than two links, so instead of `yaoihavenreborn.com`, you will see `***`

```
[Sun Mar 31 19:17:52 2013] [error] [client 69.158.139.233] PHP Warning: is_readable():
 open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-
content/plugins/content-progress/content-progress.php/content-progress-en_US.mo) is not 
within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs:.:/php:/tmp) in 
/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 339, referer: http://***/whats-
new/
```

We checked out similar posts that referred to correcting `open_basedir` errors, but creating a `vhost` did not solve the problems, and we simply do not know what to do.

Here is a copy of the `error log` after adding a `vhost`, using these directions: `http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2007/12/30/fixing-php-s-require-open_basedir-restri`

```
[Mon Apr 01 00:53:47 2013] [error] [client 99.112.124.229] PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/css/mce_modify.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/options_functions.php on line 1209, referer: http://***/forums/forum/yaoi-haven-reborn/
[Mon Apr 01 00:53:47 2013] [error] [client 99.112.124.229] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/options_functions.php on line 1210, referer: http://***/forums/forum/yaoi-haven-reborn/
[Mon Apr 01 00:53:47 2013] [error] [client 99.112.124.229] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/options_functions.php on line 1211, referer: http://***/forums/forum/yaoi-haven-reborn/
[Mon Apr 01 00:53:47 2013] [error] [client 99.112.124.229] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/options_functions.php on line 1212, referer: http://***/forums/forum/yaoi-haven-reborn/
[Mon Apr 01 00:53:49 2013] [error] [client 67.1.158.170] PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/css/mce_modify.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/options_functions.php on line 1209, referer: http://***/forums/topic/blah-blah-favorite-gamesmusic-and-making-friends3/
[Mon Apr 01 00:53:50 2013] [error] [client 108.29.88.87] PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/options_functions.php on line 1212, referer: http://***/forums/topic/blah-blah-favorite-gamesmusic-and-making-friends3/
```

Thank you for any and all help :)

Answer (score 0):

The file permissions is not set correctly in your `www` folder:
You should set readeable the files and folders in your project for your `www-data` user(group).

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/ #set the usergroup for all files, directories in www folder
sudo chmod -R g+r /var/www # make all file/dir readeable by group
find /var/www/ -type d | xargs sudo chmod g+xs //make all dir executeable (and set the group rights inherited by newly created files, dirs in the future, so you dont need to repeat the permission settings when you will create new files.
```

In the commands below, change /var/www to your projects root directory, if there is multiple projects in the server, and you have problems only with the current project.

And you should set writeable, what files need to be written by php:

```
sudo chmod g+w /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/css/mce_modify.css
//repeat this on all file need to be written by your webapp
```

Comment: O.k. So I need to make the files readable, but which files and how do I do that? How do I change /var/www to my projects directory? If you could be a little more specific (regarding steps), I would greatly appreciate it Kovge :)

Comment: WHERE DOES THIS CODE GO?!?!?!?!